# How do i import and export Localizations files in a cocoa application xcode so others can translate it?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm currently working on a mac application to which I added `localizations`. I want to know how i can `export` them so that others can translate it and once that is done how do I `import` the localization files so that I can use them in my application again. I saw a bunch of stuff saying got to editor and there you'll see "Export for localization.." I tried to look for that but couldn't find it. I'm using xcode 10.1.

Comment: The menu items will be in the Editor menu when you select the project in the Project Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was directly copy the .string file and give it a different name(i.e name of the language to be translated) you can find these files in the project files they're usually located in the folder `<short form of language name>.lproj` (for example fr.lproj for french) these will exist in the main project folder containing all the files, Inside these language folders you will find a the `Main.strings` files. Make a copy of the `Main.strings` file rename it to something like `french.strings` and give it to your translator once it's done rename it to `Main.strings` again and replace the original file of the respect language.

It's a bit tedious but it's the method I use since i can't find the export localizations option either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your context, so I'm not sure if it is maybe an overkill for you, but I use phrase.com to deal with translations. The usual flow is simple and convenient for the developers, with their CLI you can just do `phraseapp push` to get your keys into the system for translations, and then when it's done you just do `phraseapp pull` to get the translated keys locally.